# Illustration of the Korbanos

Tags: korban

Is there a resource that provides visual illustration of what the korbanos looked like. Perhaps a visual companion to sefer vayikra?

Comment: Which part? What a lamb vs. a ram looks like? Which visceral fats were burned? (To the untrained eye, it all looks like a big blob.) Where the blood was sprinkled?

Comment: @Shalom Yes to all of the above. It doesn't need to be compiled into a single resource, but that is the type of material i am looking for.

Comment: I believe the Temple Institute sells a few books/pamphlets that explain and illustrate them

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of contemporary books that use visual illustrations to teach the korbanot.

There's the [Temple Institute](https://www.templestore.co.il/product-page/%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9)'s *Avodat Hamikdash*, which goes through the halakhot from Vayikra with diagrams and charts. Here's an example of a page:

[image]

There are also books on more specific subjects. [Machshevet Betzalel](https://mbb.co.il/product-category/%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99/%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%9A-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%99/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%9A-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%99/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%9A-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%99/) has a bunch of individual diagrams on the korbanot that they make for school children. For the korban pesach, there's *[Seder Amirat Korban Pesach](http://www.zolsefer.co.il/%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8-%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%9F-%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97-%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%A1%D7%A8%D7%98-%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%9F-%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97.html)*. Here's an example:

[image]

For a companion to *Vayikra* in English, check out [The Koren Tanakh of the Land of Israel](https://korenpub.com/products/the-koren-tanakh-of-the-land-of-israel-leviticus).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.